# illegal self closing node notation for empty nodes - outputting XHTML with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, validation, xpath, xhtml

I am processing an XML compliant input of XHTML using XPATH in PHP like this:

```
$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(utf8_encode($temp));
[...]
$temp=utf8_decode($xml->saveXML());
```

The problem that arises is that nodes that may not be self closing according to the HTML5 specs, e.g.

```
<textarea id="something"></textarea>
```

or a div to leverage by JS

```
<div id="someDiv" class="whaever"></div>
```

come back out as

```
<textarea id="something" />
```

and

```
<div id="someDiv" class="whaever" />
```

I currently address this by using `str_replace`, but that's nonsese as I need to match individual cases. How can I solve this?

At the same time XPATH insists on putting out

```
xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
```

and on individual nodes freshly created, it puts stuff like `<default:p>`. How do I stop that without resorting to stupid search and replace like this:

```
$temp=str_replace(' xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" '," ",$temp);
$temp=str_replace(' xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"'," ",$temp);
$temp=str_replace('<default:',"<",$temp);
$temp=str_replace('</default:',"</",$temp);
```

?

**EDIT:** I'm really getting trouble with the stupid search and replace and I do not intend to attack the output XHTML with RegExp. Consider this example:

```
<div id="videoPlayer0" class="videoPlayerPlacement" data-xml="video/cp_IV_a_1.xml"/>
```

Obviously self-closing divs are illegal (at least in one context where I cannot output as mime application/xhtml+xml but am forced to use mime text/html) and in all other cases they sure don't validate.

Comment: using `$xml->saveHTML()` is not an option as the output can't be delivered as `application/xhtml+xml` anymore

Comment: XPath returns nodes, it doesn't do serialization. I don't know the PHP world, but you've identified the wrong culprit: it's PHP that is deciding whether to serialize with or without self-closing tags, not XPath. If you were using an XSLT serializer, you could select method="html" and all would be well.

Comment: I don't have answers to the two questions, but I just want to remark that *IF* you use application.xhtml+xml for a MIME type, *and* the result is well-formed XML, browsers will happily process `<div/>` or `<hr></hr>` exactly as needed.

Comment: @Mr Lister but the HTM won't validate and it would be nice if it did that. The specs exist for a reason (whatever the reason might be that e.g a textarea may not be self closing) - in JS one would create DOM nodes like that all the time, as the browsers don't mind it...

Comment: @Michael Kay it probably is PHP's DOMDocument class then. That has a `->saveHTML()` method but it's useless for XHTML as it won't serialize in an XML compatible form. I don't use any of this often so I figured someone might know what to do differently.

Comment: can you try it with `$dom->saveXml($dom, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);`

Comment: Just to be clear. What you are seeking is a polyglot serialization of the DOM? One that will work both as `text/html` HTML and also be well formed XML?

Comment: @Chetan Ameta Thanks but that just produces different illegal markup like `<br></br>` See edit 2 to the question please.

Comment: @Alohci I guess what I seek is an XML serialization of the DOM that only allows what the HTML5 spec defines as void elements be self closing nodes and enforces all others not to be empty. So that the result will pass HTML validation and yes can be used as mime type text/html if need be.

Comment: If you want to read/create HTML5 you can use https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to normalize "non void" tags using a trick. It is not an official solution, but it works.

```
function export_html(DOMDocument $dom)
{
    $voids = [
        'area',
        'base',
        'br',
        'col',
        'colgroup',
        'command',
        'embed',
        'hr',
        'img',
        'input',
        'keygen',
        'link',
        'meta',
        'param',
        'source',
        'track',
        'wbr',
    ];

    // Every empty node; 
    // there is no reason to match nodes with content inside.
    $query = '//*[not(node())]';
    $nodes = (new DOMXPath($dom))->query($query);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if (in_array($node->nodeName, $voids)) {
            // A void tag.
            continue;
        }
        // Not a void tag. We inject a placeholder content.
        $node->appendChild(new DOMComment('NOT_VOID'));
    }
    
    // We remove the placeholders.
    return str_replace('<!--NOT_VOID-->', '', $dom->saveXML());
}
```

In your example

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(<<<XML
<html>
    <textarea id="something"></textarea>
    <div id="someDiv" class="whaever"></div>
</html>
XML
);
```

`echo export_html($dom);` will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <textarea id="something"></textarea>
    <div id="someDiv" class="whaever"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Free from regular expressions and fully XML compatible just like I asked, so let's accept this new one... Too bad this wasn't here yesterday. I would have gladly passed those +100 rep to you. Neat trick with that comment.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't mind about rep, the important is it solves your problem. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Should you not know that **HTML5 can be written and served as XML** look at this: [*"It seems not very clear for many people. So let’s set the record straight. HTML 5 can be written in html and XML."*](http://w3.org/blog/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml)

Next to actually serve any PHP example as XML set the according header:

```
header("content-type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8");
```

In actual XML documents you cannot have any self closing tags written without a closing slash. No `<br>` instead of `</br>` etc. With that prelude let's go on...

We found that using the **LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG** option in

```
$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(utf8_encode($temp));
  // do stuff with the DOM
$temp=utf8_decode($xml->saveXML(NULL, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG));
```

does not "solve" the problem but reverses it. The HTML5 spec [names a number of "void elements"](http://w3.org/blog/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml). they are: `area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr` and to quote the spec on them: "Void elements can't have any contents (since there's no end tag, no content can be put between the start tag and the end tag)."

Because of their defined lack of content the void elements can be used to get this right by a simple RegExp (in lack of an actual solution):

```
$temp = preg_replace('#></(area|base|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|keygen|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)>#si', '/>', $temp);
```

After which we can go on with the other stupid fixes I had in the question:

```
$temp=str_replace(' xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"','',$temp);
$temp=str_replace('<default:',"<",$temp);
$temp=str_replace('</default:',"</",$temp);
```

Comment: The +100 Bounty on this question was meant to find an actual solution instead of a dumb work around. Too bad half of that bounty will automatically go to an answer attempting that work around in a clumsy way without even grasping the XML output part of the question...