# How to generically turn self closing divs into <div></div> using PHP and preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

This is a bad idea but I need to move on until I find an actual solution. [Just spent 100 rep on a bounty to do so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034229/how-to-avoid-illegal-self-closing-nodes-for-empty-nodes-when-outputting-xhtml-wi)

Anyway, I have a bunch of divs like this:

```
<div id="videoPlayer0" class="videoPlayerPlacement" data-xml="video/cp_IV_a_1.xml"/>
```

The number in the ID is variable as is the data-href. Both need to be preserved. 
I need the divs in this form:

```
<div id="videoPlayer0" class="videoPlayerPlacement" data-xml="video/cp_IV_a_1.xml"></div>
```

So my question is how to achieve the above conversion with preg_match_all (shame on us for using it on HTML).

To whoever stumbles upon this question once it's answered: 
Don't use RegExp on HTML. Search SO to find out why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex solution:

```
$result = preg_replace('#<(div|textarea)([^>]*?)/>#si', '<$1$2></$1>', $temp);
```

You can add other tag names to the pipe-delimited list, as desired.

It is not perfect. the following will not get replaced:

```
<div attrib = ">" />
```

And the following will erroneously be replaced:

```
<script>
    if (s.indexOf('<div/>')==-1) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Especially for pinting out the weaknesses. Folks: Don't use this ;-)

Comment: For my use case this quick and dirty fix will do. I don't have any inline script at that stage but have a `%%JS%%` and swap that out later as the dynamic scripts accumulate with the page.

Comment: I added `span|script` and it does fit pretty well for the time being. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution, not using regex, would be to utilise the DOMDocument. In the code below the output is piped to a text file in order that you can verify the actual result - I think this is more or less what you were trying to accomplish.

```
<?php

    $strhtml='<div id="videoPlayer0" class="videoPlayerPlacement" data-xml="video/cp_IV_a_1.xml"/>
                <div id="videoPlayer1" class="videoPlayerPlacement" data-xml="video/cp_IV_a_2.xml"/>
                <div id="videoPlayer2" class="videoPlayerPlacement" data-xml="video/cp_IV_a_3.xml"/>';

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $strhtml, 'utf-8' ) );
    libxml_clear_errors();


    $body=$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $tmp=new DOMDocument;
    foreach( $body->childNodes as $div ){
        if( $div->nodeType==1 ){
             $clone = $div->cloneNode(true);    
             $tmp->appendChild($tmp->importNode($clone,true));
        }
    }


    file_put_contents( 'c:/temp/domdump.txt', $tmp->saveHTML() );
    $dom=null;
?>
```

Comment: Yes if you'd get away with using ´$tmp->saveHTML()` which I don't. Take a look at the question I linked to and have the +100 bounty on. That has all the details why DOMDocument fails for me and why I am trying to implement a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: I did post it there but then deleted it - this question and the other are significantly different in their detail

Comment: Yes absolutely. This one is just looking for a quick and dirty fix (using RegExp as asked for) while the other looks for an actual solution. I expect the other to take some time to get answered - if ever. But do leave your answer in place it's the better solution for a wide number of cases.